# x11vnc view only password

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Настраиваю доступ к рабочему столу debian 10 xfce как полный так и для просмотра.
Полный доступ у меня получилось настроить, но так чтобы был еще и доступ для просмотра не могу настроить.
Смотрел в интернете много инструкций, там сказано что это возможно, но как сделать это на практике не нашел примеров как запустить x11vnc так, чтобы можно был полный доступ и доступ только для просмотра.
Есть статья: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html там сказано что нужно использовать ключ -viewpasswd string, но куда его вставлять и как использовать пока не понял, пробовал при запуске вставлять, x11vnc вообще не запускается.
Мне нужно чтобы был пароль для полного доступа и только для просмотра, кто знает подскажите.

Comment: это опция программы *x11vnc*: `$ x11vnc -viewpasswd "пароль для просмотра" другие опции и параметры`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем большое спасибо за подсказки, я нашел то что мне нужно, путем перебора всевозможных ключей.
Вот строка запуска, которая запускает x11vnc для полного доступа и для просмотра в зависимости какой пароль ввести:

```
x11vnc -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -passwd PASSWORD -viewpasswd password -rfbport 5900 -shared
```

В данном случае ключ -passwd пароль для полного доступа, ключ -viewpasswd пароль для просмотра, но в таком случае пароли видны в командной строке.
Как оказалось, что при использовании зашифрованных паролей ключ -rfbauth не совместим с такими ключами как -passwd, -viewpasswd, и -passwdfile
Поэтому у меня и не получалось хранить пароль для полного доступа в файле а для просмотра в командной строке. Меня устраивает и так, поскольку я получил то, что хотел. Надеюсь может еще кому то пригодится.